# Invoke Camera intent and get image data without using @Override onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, ane

I need to call Camera intent and get taken photo back but I'm in situation where I can't override any Activity to make use of onActivityResult method.

Is there any other way to get this data ?

I've read about PreferenceManager.OnActivityResultListener but I think it's not the case.

Comment: in what situation is it not possible to override onActivityResult?

Comment: what is the problem with onActivityResult?

Comment: Ok, my fault for not expalaining details :). I'm going to create Adobe AIR NativeExtension. I have particular .jar libraries for this purpose. To return result to adobe AIR done by Android classes I'm overriding FREFunction class http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WS24fe7069b89c5bc5-6148f737132a836f332-8000.html and I can operate on FREContext object which can return me Activity by using contex.getActivity(). Now I need to show camera, that's easy task but I can't override FREContext to have this onActivityResult... I know, It's a little bit complicated...